# Why NSDate's dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 modifies its input?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm running the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
  NSTimeInterval interval = date.timeIntervalSince1970;
  NSDate *newDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];

  if (![date isEqualToDate:newDate]) {
    NSLog(@"Not equal!");
  }
}
```

Surprisingly, in many iterations the dates are not equal to each other. How can that be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disassembling `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` shows that it calls `-initWithIntervalSinceReferenceDate:`:

```
CoreFoundation`+[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:]:
    0x10fd39430 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x10fd39431 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10fd39434 <+4>:  pushq  %rbx
    0x10fd39435 <+5>:  pushq  %rax
    0x10fd39436 <+6>:  movsd  %xmm0, -0x10(%rbp)
    0x10fd3943b <+11>: movq   0x2d8146(%rip), %rsi      ; "alloc"
    0x10fd39442 <+18>: movq   0x29edc7(%rip), %rbx      ; (void *)0x000000010f35e940: objc_msgSend
    0x10fd39449 <+25>: callq  *%rbx
    0x10fd3944b <+27>: movsd  -0x10(%rbp), %xmm0        ; xmm0 = mem[0],zero 
    0x10fd39450 <+32>: addsd  0x1f9d58(%rip), %xmm0     ; _CFLog_os_trace_type_map + 16
    0x10fd39458 <+40>: movq   0x2d9041(%rip), %rsi      ; "initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:"
    0x10fd3945f <+47>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10fd39462 <+50>: callq  *%rbx
    0x10fd39464 <+52>: movq   0x2d81b5(%rip), %rsi      ; "autorelease"
    0x10fd3946b <+59>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10fd3946e <+62>: movq   %rbx, %rax
    0x10fd39471 <+65>: addq   $0x8, %rsp
    0x10fd39475 <+69>: popq   %rbx
    0x10fd39476 <+70>: popq   %rbp
    0x10fd39477 <+71>: jmpq   *%rax
    0x10fd39479 <+73>: nopl   (%rax)
```

Additionally, the input to the initializer is `secs - 978307200` (or, `secs - NSTimeIntervalSince1970`), which is the time difference between 1970 and the reference date. This computation, while subtracting an integer (double) from a double can change the fraction of the input value due to rounding errors. For example, here's a date that failed the test:

```
date: Sun Mar 25 17:54:39 2018 (543682479.8504179716),
newDate: Sun Mar 25 17:54:39 2018 (543682479.8504180908)
```

Since `log2(543682479.8504179716 + NSTimeIntervalSince1970) ~ 30.5` and `log2(543682479.8504179716) ~ 29.01`, the exponent of the double value needs to be adjusted and the mantissa needs to be normalized, which may affect the fractional value.

The solution is to use the `+dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:` factory method instead, which directly initializes an `NSDate` without an additional computation.

Comment: You really do not need a disassembly to see that `initWithIntervalSinceReferenceDate:` is sent. This is the usual initialization pattern However, the rounding is intended, not a unintended rounding failure.

Comment: This is answer correct; you can see this loss of floating-point precision extremely easily without involvement from `NSDate`: `NSTimeInterval t1 = 543682479.8504179716; NSTimeInterval t2 = (t1 + NSTimeIntervalSince1970) - NSTimeIntervalSince1970; printf("%d", t1 == t2); // => 0` The floating-point values lose enough precision here to no longer be equal in exact comparison.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, while `initWithIntervalSinceReferenceDate:` is marked as the designated initializer, it's unclear how the input time interval is processed without looking at the actual code. This is also not documented anywhere in `NSDate`'s documentation.

Comment: I run in your problem years ago and after a long research I found the explanation, likely on a mailing list or so. However, a convenienced allocator always calls its counterpart initialiser, even it is not the designated initializer. The property of being designated or not is important for the way from init to init, only.

Comment: The disassembly is a great counter example to what you wrote: you expected it to call `-initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` (the counterpart initializer), but it called the designated initializer directly. In any case I believe it's outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The methods referring to 1970 are used for BSD-style date intervals since 1970. There is a resolution defined, IIRC milliseconds. Therefore the `NSTimeValue` value, is rounded intentionally to that specs. You cannot expect the value transformed and retransformed to be the same value because of this rounding.

Only use these methods, when you get a BSD time. This is documented:

> This method is useful for creating NSDate objects from time_t values returned by BSD system functions.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1591576-datewithtimeintervalsince1970

However, as said by StatusReport, dates are floating point numbers. Testing for equality is always dangerous. I. e. when you store a date with Core Data it is "rounded" to the resolution of the SQL column.

Comment: This is not correct. `NSDate` doesn't have a time resolution, nor are the values actually rounded; the issue is loss of floating-point precision, as @StatusReport says.

Comment: Or rather, the time resolution of an `NSTimeInterval` is whatever fits in a `double`. The implementation of `-initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` just takes the time interval given, subtracts `NSTimeIntervalSince1970` (to calculate a time interval since the reference date), and calls out to `-initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:`; there is no rounding involved.

Comment: I did not say, that `NSDate` have a resolution. I said, that the "since1970" property ha a solution. In contrast to `NSTimeInterval` is is an integer.

Comment: That's still not correct. `-initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` subtracts `NSTimeIntervalSince1970` from the given time interval and passes the result to `-initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:`; the `timeIntervalSince1970` method takes the time since reference date and adds `NSTimeIntervalSince1970` back. You can prove this to yourself extremely easily:

Comment: for (NSTimeInterval i = 0; i < 10000000; i += 0.1) {
            NSTimeInterval t1 = (i - NSTimeIntervalSince1970) + NSTimeIntervalSince1970;
            NSTimeInterval t2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:i].timeIntervalSince1970;
            if (t1 != t2) {
                NSLog(@"%f != %f", t1, t2);
            }
        }

Comment: Hard to format the code in comments, but the above prints nothing. For every time interval, round-tripping through `-initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` and `timeIntervalSince1970` returns _exactly_ the same result as doing the addition and subtraction yourself. You can play with the resolution of the loop, it'll just take longer. There is no rounding anywhere in this code; `NSDate` never modifies the value you give it, just wraps it.